# NA produced in linear regression model

Tags: r

I have read similar posts to this but my problem is not resolved by the answers given. I want to do a v simple linear regression to see if bite incidence is related to district, zone (vacc or control) and year.   As you can see in the output one of the districts RORYA is given NA coefficients, and I get the message "Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)". 
I have read up on this and it seems its to do with co-linearity of factors. 
One solution given is to add -1 to the call, which removes the intercept but does not solve my problem as RORYA district still has NAs in the summary output.

Another solution I have tried is changing the order of the explanatory variables in the call.  This does change things...Rorya district suddenly has coefficients but the Zone variable becomes NA'd.  Neither of which is good as I would like a coefficent for all the explanatory variables.

I was wondering whether anyone might know why this is happening and whether there is a solution to this problem so that all the variables can have coefficients?

Thanks in advance.

A Reproducible example:

```
df <- structure(list(DISTRICT = structure(c(1L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 
1L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 
2L, 4L), .Label = c("BUNDA", "MASWA", "MUSOMA", "RORYA", "SERENGETI", 
"TARIME"), class = "factor"), zone = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("c", "v"), class = "factor"), 
year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("2010", 
"2011", "2012", "2013"), class = "factor"), bites = c(7.461327937, 
NA, NA, NA, 35.16164185, 26.39109338, 57.89990479, 1.47191729, 
3.608371422, 51.36718605, NA, 16.21167165, 46.85713945, 15.89670673, 
5.212092054, 259.8137381, 30.80276062, 20.73585909, 10.44585911, 
9.420270656, 7.617673001, 307.4586643, 27.31565565, 30.16124958
), deaths = c(0, NA, NA, NA, 0, 1.508062479, 0.298453117, 
0, 0, 0, NA, 2.262093719, 0.298453117, 0.294383458, 0, 2.233355915, 
0.581184163, 1.131046859, 0.298453117, 0.588766916, 1.202790474, 
2.977807887, 0, 1.885078099)), .Names = c("DISTRICT", "zone", 
"year", "bites", "deaths"), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = "data.frame")
```

Code:

```
summary(df )
names(df)
attach(df)
is.numeric(year)
df$year  <- as.factor(as.character(df$year))
is.factor(df$year)

model1 <- lm(bites ~   zone + DISTRICT-1 +year, data = df)
summary(model1)

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_1.0.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] colorspace_1.2-4 digest_0.6.4     gtable_0.1.2     MASS_7.3-34      munsell_0.4.2   plyr_1.8.1       proto_0.3-10     Rcpp_0.11.2     
[9] reshape2_1.4     scales_0.2.4     stringr_0.6.2    tools_3.1.0
```

Answer (score 6):

When you fit a model with factors (in this case the DISTRICT) and no intercept, the method is to create a dummy binary variable for each factor. So internally there's a binary 0/1 value for "Is case in DISTRICT RORYA". Now the `zone` variable for each of those cases is `c`, so you have perfect agreement between `DISTRICT==RORYA` and `zone`. The variables are perfectly collinear, and hence the warning:

```
Coefficients: (1 not defined because of singularities)
```

and the inability to define both parameters. So `NA` appears.

In your data all districts are one of the zones:

```
> table(df$DISTRICT, df$zone)

            c v
  BUNDA     0 4
  MASWA     4 0
  MUSOMA    4 0
  RORYA     4 0
  SERENGETI 0 4
  TARIME    0 4
```

So you are going to have trouble including the `zone` and `DISTRICT` variable in any analysis. You can't have a coefficient for the `zone` and **any** of the districts because there simply isn't enough information to discriminate between any district and its zone.